# Custom Idle Animation not working

Tags: unity, c#, animation, sprites

I'm trying to insert the idle animation in the if-else statement but whenever I run the game, it doesn't play the idle animation, just the running animation. The base of this algorithm is from the Youtube tutorial of the Pokemon game. Here is the link to that : [Custom Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BsUZy_QCQo&list=PLLf84Zj7U26kfPQ00JVI2nIoozuPkykDX&index=28)

This is the code for the Character Animation

```
var prevAnim = currentAnim;

if (MoveX == 1)
{
    currentAnim = runRightanim;
}
else if (MoveX == -1)
{
    currentAnim = runLeftanim;
}
if (MoveY == 1)
{
    currentAnim = runUpanim;
}
else if (MoveY == -1)
{
    currentAnim = runDownanim;
}
if(currentAnim != prevAnim || isMoving != waspreviouslymoving)
{
    currentAnim.Start();
}


if (isMoving)
{
    currentAnim.HandleUpdate();
}
else 
{
    if (MoveX == 1)
    {
        currentAnim = idleRightanim;
      
    }
    if (MoveX == -1)
    {
        currentAnim = idleLeftanim;
    }
    if (MoveY == 1)
    {
        currentAnim = idleUpanim;
    }
    if (MoveY == -1)
    {
        currentAnim = idleDownanim;
    }
}

waspreviouslymoving = isMoving;
```

This is the code for the Sprite renderer

```
 SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
List<Sprite> frames;
float frameRate;
int currentframe; //tracks frame
float timer; //tracks time
public SpriteAnimator(List<Sprite> frames, SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer, float frameRate = 0.16f)
{
 //Initializer
    this.frames = frames;
    this.spriteRenderer = spriteRenderer;
    this.frameRate = frameRate;
}
public void Start()
{
    currentframe = 0;
    timer = 0f;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = frames[0];
}

public void HandleUpdate()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer > frameRate)
    {
        currentframe = (currentframe + 1) % frames.Count; //current frame==last frame, loops frames
        spriteRenderer.sprite = frames[currentframe];
        timer -= frameRate; //reset timer
    }
}
```

Im new to game Development in Unity, I hope for your spare time, thank you~

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `isMoving`? This looks like it's manually doing things that an Animator Controller Graph can automate for you - have you considered using that system instead?

Comment: Also, please don't tag `C#` questions with the deprecated language `UnityScript` - the tag guidance reminds you that Unity has not supported that language in half a decade, so make sure you're reading those tips when tagging your posts.